# EJB as WebService in Enterprise Application Project

Tags: java, web-services, soap, glassfish, ejb

i have created an Maven Enterprise Application Project in Netbeans. I have created an example-EJB, a Remote and a local interface. Now i want to publish a SOAP webservice by using these EJB, but there is something i'm doing wrong, because in glassfish i can't view the endpoint (with wsdl etc.). But it is listed as a component:

**Component Name:** RecommendationSOAPService, SHITSTORMRECOMMENDER

**Module Name:** ShitstormRecommender-ejb-1.0.jar, ShitstormRecommender-ejb-1.0.jar

**Type:** StatelessSessionBean, StatelessSessionBean

My EJB:

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import org.andy.dto.Recommendation;
import org.andy.dto.RecommendationRequest;

    @Stateless(name = "SHITSTORMRECOMMENDER")
    public class ShitstormRecommenderEJB implements ShitstormReommenderEJBRemote,
            ShitstormRecommenderEJBLocal {

        @Override
        public List<Recommendation> getRecommendation(RecommendationRequest request) {
            Recommendation r1 = new Recommendation("Task 2", 10, "blubb");
            Recommendation r2 = new Recommendation("Task 1", 5, "bla");
            List<Recommendation> recommendations = new ArrayList<>();
            recommendations.add(r1);
            recommendations.add(r2);
            return recommendations;
        }

    }
```

My Remote Interface (Local interface looks like the same only with @local):

```
@Remote
public interface ShitstormReommenderEJBRemote {
    public List<Recommendation> getRecommendation(RecommendationRequest request);
}
```

My WebService-Class (located in the ejb-Container with the interfaces and the EJB):

```
package org.andy.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.andy.dto.Recommendation;
import org.andy.dto.RecommendationRequest;
import org.andy.ejb.ShitstormReommenderEJBRemote;

@WebService(
        name= "ShitstormRecommender",
        portName = "ShitstormRecommenderPort",
        serviceName = "ShitstormRecommenderService",
        targetNamespace = "http://shitstormRecommendation.org"
        )
@Stateless
public class RecommendationSOAPService{

    @EJB
    private ShitstormReommenderEJBRemote recommender;

    @WebMethod
    public String sayCiao(){
        return "ciao";
    }
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="recommendations")
    public List<Recommendation> getRecommendation(
            @WebParam(name="recommendationRequest") RecommendationRequest request) {
        return recommender.getRecommendation(request);
    }
}
```

Maybe you can say, what i have to do to bring it to work? I have tried it out from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tleyeLV86Y). There it seems to be working, but i think i have forgot something.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to access the wsdl in your browser through: ```http://localhost:8080/ShitstormRecommenderService/RecommendationSOAPService?wsdl``` assuming your server is running on port 8080

Comment: yes, i have tried it, but i get only HTTP 404 Not found error. Maybe i have to configure something in the ejb-jar.xml?